# Link for "A spine for Teichmüller space", preprint by Thurston

Tags: reference-request, teichmuller-theory

Can someone please give any link or mention any source where I can find the following preprint. 
**W.Thurston, A spine for Teichmüller space, preprint, three pages, 1986.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find a quite detailed summary of Thurston's unpublished manuscript, which apparently is only three pages, as well as a critical discussion on page 13 and following of [this 2014 paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0877) by Lizhen Ji. I presume that an email to [the author](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~lji/) will get you Thurston's manuscript as well.